# Lista ordenable con valores de padre/hijo ForeignKey | Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Me encuentro en el listado de administración de *Django* dónde aparecen todos los modelos almacenados bajo (valga la redundancia) un mismo modelo.

Hasta aquí todo bien, ahora necesito mostrar en el `list_display` del `admin` información del padre, el cual está relacionado con un `Foreign Key`. Para ello hago esto en el propio `modelo.py`:

```
def getFatherX(self):
        qs = self.RelatedForeignKeyExample
        result = qs.X
        return result

# Esto es dentro del modelo hijo
```

Y en el  `list_display` del `admin`:

```
list_display = ['getFatherX']
```

De esta forma, ya tengo información del padre visible sin tener que ir entrando en cada uno.

---

**Problema:**

Lo que ocurre es que al realizarlo de esta forma no puedo ordenar clickando encima de su columna:

[image: Imagen para explicar mejor dónde se haría el click]

Simplemente no me da la opción de poder clickar encima para ordenarlo.

Comment: Hola Fran, bienvenido. ¿Podrías añadir la respuesta a la pregunta por separado? Así la pregunta no aparecerá "sin responder" y la comunidad podrá llegar a la solución más fácilmente si alguien busca algo similar :-). Saludos!

Comment: Por supuesto, mañana sin falta la añado como respuesta. Muchas gracias por el aviso :) Saludos!

Comment: Genial :-) Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solución

He encontrado la solución, se me había pasado completamente el hecho de poder acceder a los campos del hijo usando la doble barra baja `__` en el campo de relación.

[Click aquí para ir a la solución](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859172/django-admin-changelist-foreignkey-from-froreignkey-sortable)